# MySQL query for restriction purposes

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

1. officers
2. yes_vote -> those officers who voted 'yes'
3. no_vote -> those officers who voted 'no'
4. not_voted -> thos officers who haven't voted yet

What I have done:

1. Check if the officer exists in yes_vote.
2. The existing data will not be shown as an option for yes_vote.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM officers 
   WHERE uuid NOT IN (SELECT officer_uuid 
                     FROM ".$table_vote." v 
                     WHERE v.resolution_uuid = '".$resolution_uuid."')"
   ```

What I have to do:

1. Check if the officer is either on the three votes tables.
2. If the officer for example is already included in yes_vote, he/she must not be shown as an option in no_vote and not_voted and so on.

Comment: please load your data and tables in sql fiddle

Comment: Why do you have 3 tables for that? You shoul have 1 table with a flag showing current voting status...

Comment: Why have you got _three_ tables for this? One would do.

Comment: Because it's easier in generating reports.

Comment: @Eli: Not true, because your SQL is more weight to manage by DBMS

Comment: @Eli Use one table. If you want you can use views to facilatate the production of reports.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your table structure is wrong but...

If you want to check the parallel existence in 3 tables:

```
SELECT * FROM officers o
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 'YES' FROM yes_vote y WHERE y.officer_uuid = o.id AND y.resolution_id = 'YOUR_VAR')
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 'NO' FROM no_vote n WHERE n.officer_uuid = o.id AND y.resolution_id = 'YOUR_VAR')
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 'NOTVOTED' FROM not_voted nv WHERE nv.officer_uuid = o.id AND y.resolution_id = 'YOUR_VAR')
```

I advice you to change your table structure, instead 3 different tables, you can create one table with the vote of officer as follow:

```
TABLE VOTE:

id (PK of vote table)
officer_uuid (FK to officers table)
resolution_uuid (FK to resolutions table)
vote_kind (with check Y, N, X)
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Check if the officer is either on the three votes tables

```
SELECT * FROM officers WHERE uuid IN (SELECT officer_uuid FROM yes_vote union SELECT officer_uuid FROM no_vote  union SELECT officer_uuid FROM not_voted )
```

2) If the officer for example is already included in yes_vote, he/she must not be shown as an option in no_vote and not_voted and so on.

I think you want to list out the officers who has entries in multiple tables and that should not be happen.
suppose you want to find officers who has multiple entries in yes_vote and no_vote

```
select * from officers where uuid in (   SELECT officer_uuid  FROM yes_vote inner join no_vote on yes_vot.officer_uuid =no_vote.officer_uuid )
```

same for not_voted

if you want to find wether officer has already given his/her vote or not.. you can use below query

```
select if(b.uuid is null,'still not voted','already voted'),a.officer_name from officers  a left join  (SELECT officer_uuid as uuid FROM yes_vote union SELECT officer_uuid as uuid FROM no_vote  union SELECT officer_uuid as uuid FROM not_voted )b   on a.uuid =b.uuid
```

Comment: The officer must vote only once. If he/she voted yes, he's/she's not allowed to vote no or not_voted anymore.

Comment: I have updated the answer so please let me know it works for you or not